# Problem running Ubuntu on crouton after updating chromeos

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, xfce, chrome-os

I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 using Crouton on a Toshiba Chromebook 2 for several months. Today I exited Crouton and restarted my chromebook. After restarting and issuing `sudo startxfce4` in the shell I received the following error

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startxfce4
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Tue Apr 14 20:43:12 PDT 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=e4e36f0d-ca2b-5940-a7fe-a61287b5a2d8/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=e4e36f0d-ca2b-5940-a7fe-a61287b5a2d8/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=45e6c45d7f91005eb3265c86cdf50fb85b6449c4 salt=d14d293f1aa4206fae2fe4284ac3a5e3de528f53b75f6b378b55c5ce1c9ddfc5" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=e4e36f0d-ca2b-5940-a7fe-a61287b5a2d8 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Apr 29 13:43:33 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f3c407bd848]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f3c40614000+0x1ad539) [0x7f3c407c1539]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f3c3f710000+0x10340) [0x7f3c3f720340]
(EE) 3: /usr/bin/X (0x7f3c40614000+0xb57a6) [0x7f3c406c97a6]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (xf86BusProbe+0x9) [0x7f3c4069d099]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x74d) [0x7f3c406ab6fd]
(EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7f3c40614000+0x59bab) [0x7f3c4066dbab]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f3c3e150ec5]
(EE) 8: /usr/bin/X (0x7f3c40614000+0x451ee) [0x7f3c406591ee]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Not unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty as another instance is using it.
```

Does anyone know what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my own problem. Downloaded the newest version of crouton and issued `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n chrootname` and everything's back to normal.

Here `chrootname` refers to the name of the chroot that can be optionally specified during the chroot creation (this defaults to the distro name, but can optionally be specified at chroot creation time with the `-n` option).

Comment: When you say `chrootname`, you mean the username used during the crouton install? Or do you mean the name of the distro being used (trusty, unity, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error where xfce4 suddently wouldn't start after an automatic update on chrome's side. Solved the problem by downloading the latest version of crouton (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) and running `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -t xfce`. (`-u` for update and `-t xfce` to specifiy xfce environment target.) I'm by no means an expert, but it worked well for me.